# Efficient, Reliable Active Objects Count

Tags: ruby, memory, garbage-collection

Is there a mechanism for getting a reliable value for the number of active objects in a Ruby environment? I've found several approaches to produce an answer, and typically they resemble:

```
c = 0   
ObjectSpace.each_object { c += 1 }
```

The unfortunate problem with this is that there's a large number of Fixnum objects created simply to tabulate, not to mention some apparent overhead of the ObjectSpace method itself.

Of course one could filter results according to class and simply ignore Fixnum objects, but that seems to be an imperfect workaround as it makes presumptions about how each_object works.

I'd just like to find a mechanism for determining how much garbage is generated between one point during operation and another as the garbage collector can be turned off for diagnostic purposes to provide an accurate benchmark.

Comment: No Fixnum objects are created here — Fixnums aren't created at all, and they aren't really objects in the underlying implementation. They have a literal representation as ints. Try typing `42.object_id` — you'll see that it's always the same value. This is why normal objects' `object_id`s are always even — the odd numbers are used for Fixnums.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was the case, however it does not appear to be so. It seems like there are a number of "fixed" Fixnums, such as 0, 1, 2, etc. but beyond a certain point they are actually allocated on demand. Using += generates a new object no matter the type.

Comment: No, it holds true for all Fixnums. It's just that not all Integers are Fixnums. After a certain point they become Bignums, which are indeed allocated on demand. And using += on a Fixnum cannot generate a new object because it is not possible to create a new Fixnum. Try it: `a=5; b=4; a+=1; b+=2; a.object_id == b.object_id`. There is one Fixnum for every number, because as I said, it has a literal representation through its `object_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do it directly with Kernel or GC.  Rails attempts to do this when benchmarking - see the [source code for active_support/testing/performance.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/25e5b0c4a8d0045715a6ad11e2898585826e4e9b/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/performance.rb#L379).  Unfortunately, it looks like all of these methods require a patched Ruby interpreter.

The RubyProf docs might also be useful; this is one of the methods that Rails attempts to use.  If you apply the patch (not sure where to find it) you should just be able to do:

`RubyProf.measure_allocations; RubyProf::ALLOCATIONS`